# Talking to GameObject and components, what is the logic?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to attain the legendary skill of mastering how to make my scripts talk with any GameObject and their components wherever they are. To do that, i watched a couple of tutorials like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrkfSqxz4jU, but my brain still seem to resist to smartness :(.

- So far, i have understood than in order to do that **i first need my
  script to find the right gameobject** in my scene (if the script is not
  attached directly to it), and assign it to a variable, with for
  example:

  myVariable = GameObject.Find ("MyGameObjectName");

**Then**, when i have found this gameobject (and eventually summoned it if it was not in my scene), i find myself at loss to figure out **how to call the right component** (and inherently, how to call the right sub-element.

- For example, i have at the moment a game object for my UI with :

**RectTransform, CanvasRenderer,UI Controller (Script),Grid Layout Group (Script)**

In order to modify the *RectTransform 's Pivot X* for example, my logic tells me to add to my script:

```
 myVariable.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();
 myVariable.RectTransform.Pivot.x = 0.75;
```

...Which get all red and bad, and i don't understand why. I am also not knowing how i am supposed to call the component GridLayoutGroup. I suppose there is a even dirtier trick in the sense that it is written (script)...

To give you another example that i find confusing, if i would type `myVariable.transform.position.x` , is it changing the RectTransform, or another hidden transform that i don't know of ?

It is confusing because i would think that logically, this should be called instead `myVariable.RectTransform.position.x` or something.

So the point of all that is: **What's the big idea** ? **What is the core concept that i am missing** ?

I am confused ! :D

Comment: GetComponent returns the desired component attached to the given gameobject. Just change the attribute of the component directly `myVariable.GetComponent<RectTransform>().pivot = new Vector2( 0.75f, 0 ) ;`. Moreover, RectTransform inherits from Transform. Thus, `myVariable.transform.position` will change the RectTransform (which **is** a Transform thanks to inheritance)

Comment: ohh thanks for this brilliant answer ! I get it now ! So happy !
Would you happen to know the issue with the GridLayoutGroup component ? It does not seem like i can get this inside the <> of my GetComponent..
Edit: Found it ! http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1031902/getcomponent-not-working-on-gridlayoutgroup.html

Comment: The [GridLayoutGroup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GridLayoutGroup.html) is a class declared inside the `UnityEngine.UI` namespace. Thus, either add `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top of your script, or call GetComponent like this : `myVariable.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.GridLayoutGroup>()`

Comment: Thanks Hellium ! This is great help that you gave me, thanks a ton !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because having public fields is bad practice (accessible from everywhere) you should use serialized fields.

I'll just use the example Vancete made up, but with a serialized field instead of a public field.

```
[SerializeField] GameObject myGo; // a space to drop a GameObject will appear in the inspector too, 
// with the benefit of not having a public field
// (not specifying public, private, protected etc. makes the field private in C#)

void Start() {
    Image myImg = myGo.GetComponent<Image>();
    myImg.sprite = // WHATEVER
    myImg.color = // YOUR PREFERRED COLOR
}
```

At the bottom of [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/549814/using-serializefield-vs-public.html) page, you'll find a nice table, comparing these modifiers.
These people [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/do-you-use-serializefield-a-lot.307079/) are all proving my concept. As the user, who wrote the last answer on the linked page, points out, even Unity is using [SerializeField] in their example project.
You'll find another proof in [this](http://www.tallior.com/unity-encapsulate-your-fields/) article.

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! I stumbled on this concept of serialization, but i did not really understand it at the time. I just starting to code seriously some weeks ago, and i am still trying to wrap up my head around the basic concepts, techniques and patterns. So much to know...
I will take your advice seriously though and look tomorrow into this Serialize stuff to understand how to use it.
thanks a lot for your time..!

Answer (score 2):

The fastest and best way to access a GameObject is declaring it as public and drag&dropping in the inspector.

GameObject.Find is slow (since it requires a tree search) and impractical (you will have problems if you rename the GameObject or change its hierarchy), things that can be avoided linking it in the mentioned way above.

For example, using GameObject.Find inside the Update is a real performance killer.

Also, if you are going to access to a GameObject component more than once, it's recommended to reference it before using it.

```
public GameObject myGo; // a space to drop a GameObject will appear in the inspector

void Start(){
    Image myImg = myGo.GetComponent<Image>();
    myImg.sprite = // WHATEVER
    myImg.color = // YOUR PREFERRED COLOR
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing at this very important aspect that is performance. Some people indicated this method of finding automatically the gameobject to avoid broken connections.
Though, i use it only in the start function, is that as performance killing ?

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to mention that Find won't find a disabled GameObject either, throwing an exception. Avoid using it when possible (99.9% cases).

Comment: Again, thank you! Such great important details to know, and that will be thanks to you :)

Comment: I don't like all these public variables in my code. This is bad practice in object oriented programming because the public fields are accessible from everywhere. I guess there should be a better method than using Find. If I find one, I'll post it as an answer to this.

Comment: Was just an example. You can do the same putting [SerializeField] before a private variable declaration.